# How to show sub field of relation in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

I use C# and EF Core. I have two model classes, `Product` and `ProductInventory`. I also have a view model class `ProductInventory`.

```
public class ProductInventory 
{ 
    public long ProductInventoryId { get; set ;}
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{ 
    public long ProductId { get; set ;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection ProductInventories { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection();
}
```

My code to select `ProductInventories`:

```
ObservableCollection<ProductInventory> Products = 
   new ObservableCollection<ProductInventory>(context.ProductInventories.ToList());
```

I want to bind `ProductName` to a DataGridColumn.

In my code behind, I can get `ProductName` with `Products[index].Product.Name` - but I don't know how to bind it to DataGridColumn.

Answer (score 0):

If you set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of your `DataGrid` to your `ObservableCollection<ProductInventory>`, you should be able to display the product name in a column like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Product.Name}" Header="Product Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I use this , but it doesn't show any thing

Comment: Are you sure that the `Product` property actually returns a product object then? What exactly does `Products` contain?

Comment: in view model I can do this Products[index].Product.Name

Comment: is there any way?

Comment: Yes, the way I showed you works assuming you have set up evertything correctly.